# How can i center div with position absolute inside td

Tags: html, css

GooD Morning ,
I'm trying to center a div inside a td.
for my td i defined aposition with relative and the div have the position absolute.
How can i center the div with out removing the poistion absolute?

Comment: We need code. Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Give the `div` a `height` and a `width`, then do `position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;`
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWGNOb

Comment: include your code if you expect help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
td{
            position: relative;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            border:1px solid grey;
        }
        div{
            position: absolute;
            width:70px;
            height:70px;
            border:1px solid green;
            right: 15px;
            bottom:15px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ok but idon't have a width and height for my td so it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you, it will center the `div` vertically and horizontally

```css
td {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        some contents
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```